Complete List of Cards From the Yugipedia MediaWiki page
I'm fairly new to using APIs, and have been working on a personal project to store my Yugioh collection.
Using Python and the Yugipedia API, is there a simple way to pull every card into a CSV file? The API is found here: https://yugipedia.com/api.php but I can't see anything about pulling card data?
This is what I've come up with so far:
import requests
import pandas as pd

def fetch_card_set_data(set_name):
    try:
        api_url = f'https://yugipedia.com/api.php?action=ask&query=[[Card%20set%20::{set_name}]]&format=json'
        response = requests.get(api_url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for HTTP request if it fails
        data = response.json()
        return data
    except (requests.HTTPError, requests.RequestException) as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data for '{set_name}': {e}")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error occurred while fetching data for '{set_name}': {e}")
        return None

def extract_info(data):
    try:
        set_name = data['query']['results'][0]['printouts']['Card set'][0]
        release_date = data['query']['results'][0]['printouts']['Release date'][0]
        return set_name, release_date
    except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:
        print(f"Error extracting information from API response: {e}")
        return None, None

def create_csv(card_sets):
    df = pd.DataFrame(card_sets, columns=['Set Name', 'Release Date'])
    df.to_csv('card_sets.csv', index=False)

def main():
    # List of card sets from the Yugipedia page
    card_sets_list = [
        'Legend of Blue Eyes White Dragon',
        # Add more set names as needed
    ]

    card_sets_info = []

    for set_name in card_sets_list:
        data = fetch_card_set_data(set_name)
        if data:
            set_info = extract_info(data)
            if set_info[0]: 
                card_sets_info.append(set_info)

    create_csv(card_sets_info)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Ideally, I would need just a complete list of all cards with their set code, rarity etc, but this is proving difficult
I've used the code mentioned above and met the error:

Error fetching data for 'Legend of Blue Eyes White Dragon': 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://yugipedia.com/api.php?action=ask&query=%5B%5BCard%20set%20::Legend%20of%20Blue%20Eyes%20White%20Dragon%5D%5D&format=json

I don't understand why I'm getting a 403 as I'm just extracting data, not manipulating it in any way?
